# Graphics.Clear a given image? C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, draw

i have code this code to draw an image on a Picture-box in my Winforms application, I was wondering if there was a way to clear an individual image instead of clearing everything.

```
public void DrawImage(Image img, Point pos)
    {
        if (GraphicsRenderer!=null)
        {
            GraphicsRenderer.DrawImage(img, pos);
        }
    }
DrawImage(Image.FromFile("image.png"), new Point(0, 0));

// then this to draw a rectangle
public void DrawRectangle(Rectangle rect, Pen pen)
    {
        if (GraphicsRenderer == null)
            GraphicsRenderer = Renderer.CreateGraphics();

        GraphicsRenderer.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
    }
DrawRectangle(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(40, 40)), Pens.Red);

// now how do i clear only the image?
```

Any help or insight is appreciated!

Comment: If `Renderer` is a `PictureBox` is a don't manipulate the Graphics on it. `PictureBox` is designed to display static images you load in. If you want to draw on a form just create a empty panel and do your drawing in the `OnPaint` event and use the `e.Graphics` object instead of using `CreateGraphics`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You'll have to redraw the entire picture, without your image.png. Your graphics calls are ultimately drawing to an underlying graphics buffer (think: raw pixel data). When you draw on that underlying graphics buffer, you overwrite what was previously there, and there is no such thing as an undo operation.

Comment: That probably warrants a new thread for discussion though I think overzealous moderators would close it as off topic. You're probably going to want to look into graphics libraries that support layering / adding to a scene of some sorts. Worst case write your own, have IRenderable and implement that from drawers, clear buffer and iterate down the list to render. What are you working on? For your example that would obviously be overkill.

Comment: @wartly Thank you friend!